# determinition of kernel of a homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ M_{2 \times 2} ( \mathbb{R} )$ be the $ \mathbb{R}$- Algebra  of all the $ 2 \times 2$- matrices with coefficients in $ \mathbb{R}$ and $ \mathbb{R}[X] $ the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{R}$ and 
 If $ \mathbf{A} \in M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})$

$ \phi : \mathbb{R}[X] \to M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})$ defined as

$ \sum_{i=0}^d r_i X^i  \rightarrow \sum_{i=o}^d r_i \mathbf{A}^i  $

Let $A$ be $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 &0\end{pmatrix} $

How can I determine the kernel of $\phi$, $kern(\phi)$  without using the Cayley Hamilton Theorem?

Comment: Kernel is generated by the minimal polynomial.. So if you can figure out the minimal polynomial without using the Cayley Hamilton's theorem, it will do.

Comment: the minimal Polynom is $ \mathbb{x}_A$ = $ \lambda ^2 $+1 right?

Comment: ... or if you can figure out the minimal polynomial *with* the Cayley Hamilton theorem, but justify the result in some other fashion.

Comment: i would be very greatfull if someone can Show me how to do it right...sitting since hours on that Topic :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Since $\Bbb R[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, the proper ideal $\ker \phi$ is generated by a single element.

A generating element cannot have degree zero, since every polynomial $p(x) = a_0$ of degree zero, $$p(A) = a_0 I \neq 0 .$$

Suppose the generating element has degree $1$, say, it is $p(x) = a_1 x + a_0$. Then, $$p(A) = \pmatrix{a_0 & a_1 \\ -a_1 & a_0} .$$
So, $p(A) = 0$ implies that $a_0 = a_1 = 0$, that is, that $p(x) = 0$, so $\ker \phi$ cannot be generated by an element of degree $1$.

Now, suppose the generating element has degree $2$, say, it is $p(x) = a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$...

Comment: would the kernel have the form of : $  r_0 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} + r_1 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ r_2 \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} + r_3 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + r_4 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ ? thank you for your answere !

Comment: Notice that you can write that expression as $(r_0 - r_2 + r_4) I + (r_1 - r_3) A$...